# How can I embed HTML file into MatLab GUI?

Tags: html, matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to display a html site on my gui direkt , I only can do it on a another windows (figure) but not in my GUI ...

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hExp = actxcontrol('Shell.Explorer.2',conSize,hObject);  % Create the control
Navigate(hExp,varargin{1});
```

you need to pass the main object hObject to the command and the windows will be added

like this one 
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-internet-explorer-program-in-a-matlab-figure.html